# Python class's dictionary's value is changing when assigned to a different variable

Tags: python, function, class, return

I am new to Python, I have a class somthing like:

```
class UserInfo():
    def __init__(self):
        self.level = 1
        self.type = 'A'
        self.info = {
            'name ' : 'John',
            'age ' : 20,
            'gender  ' : 'Male',
            'job' : 'student',
        }

    def getInfo(self):
        return self.info
```

etc.....

Then I create an instance of the class:

```
ui = UserInfo()

# display original class info
print(ui.getInfo())
# {
#    'name ' : 'John',
#    'age ' : 20,
#    'gender  ' : 'Male',
#    'job' : 'student',
# }

myinfo = ui.getInfo()
# change "myinfo"
myinfo.update({
    'name ' : 'May',
    'age ' : 18,
    'gender  ' : 'Female',
    'job' : 'lecturer',
})
```

But when i try to display original class info again, i get:

```
print(ui.getInfo())
# {
#   'name ' : 'May',
#   'age ' : 18,
#   'gender  ' : 'Female',
#   'job' : 'lecturer',
# }
```

What i expected is

```
print(myinfo)
# {
#   'name ' : 'May',
#   'age ' : 18,
#   'gender  ' : 'Female',
#   'job' : 'lecturer',
# }

print(ui.getInfo())
# {
#    'name ' : 'John',
#    'age ' : 20,
#    'gender  ' : 'Male',
#    'job' : 'student',
# }
```

Why i update the `myinfo` but it change the value of the class as well?
How to avoid this? I just want to amend for only `myinfo`

---

**EDIT 1:**

Thanks to all answered my question.
I just tried using `return self.info.copy()`
and it work fine when i try to do `myinfo.update`

But now i have another question, when my dict contain another dict, if i try to edit the dict inside, it not work again:

```
class UserInfo():
        def __init__(self):
            self.level = 1
            self.type = 'A'
            self.info = {
                'name ' : 'John',
                'age ' : 20,
                'gender  ' : 'Male',
                'job' : 'student',
                'favorite' : {
                    'food' : 'pizza',
                    'sport' : 'badminton',
                    'game' : 'none',
                },
            }

        def getInfo(self):
            return self.info.copy()
```

```
    ui = UserInfo()
    print(ui.getInfo())
    # {
    #   'name ': 'John',
    #   'age ': 20,
    #   'gender  ': 'Male',
    #   'job': 'student',
    #   'favorite': {
    #       'food': 'pizza',
    #       'sport': 'badminton',
    #       'game': 'none'
    #   }
    #}

    myinfo = ui.getInfo()
    myinfo['favorite'].update({'game' : 'mobile'})
    print(ui.getInfo())
    #   {
    #     'name ': 'John',
    #     'age ': 20,
    #     'gender  ': 'Male',
    #     'job': 'student',
    #     'favorite': {
    #       'food': 'pizza',
    #       'sport': 'badminton',
    #       'game': 'mobile'
    #     }
    #   }
```

Comment: ...  because `update` mutates the dict in-place, and your instance attribute `info` is still referring to that same dict object. You could make `getInfo` something like `return self.info.copy()`

Comment: Thanks for replied. It work fine with return ```.copy()``` when i do ```myinfo.update```, but when the dict contain another dict, its not working again (I already edit my post)

Comment: Because in that case you need to create a *deep copy*. The best solution is to not design your program around mutable state like that

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Oh i see, i will look around my code again, really thanks for replied!

Answer (score 0):

How about you just copy the returned dictionary?

```
myInfo = ui.getInfo()
```

**EDIT**

To answer your follow-up question,

When you use copy, it returns a different dictionary with the same objects. That means if you change an element A of dictionary B, which is a mutable object, like a dictionary, then the dictionary A changes in both B and B's copy.

To avoid this, you need a copy which also copies all the elements. There's a method exactly for this in python: deepcopy().

So for the desired result, do the following:

```
myInfo = ui.getInfo().deepcopy()
```

Comment: Or in one step with `myinfo = ui.getInfo().copy()`

Answer (score 0):

You are receiving the same class because you are altering the values you originally put in. I would advise passing the dictionary as an attribute into the class, like so:

```
class UserInfo():
   def __init__(self, dict_info):
      self.level = 1
      self.type = 'A'
      self.info = dict_info

   def getInfo(self):
      return self.info

# pass the dictionary through the class instance
dict_info = {
        'name ' : 'John',
        'age ' : 20,
        'gender  ' : 'Male',
        'job' : 'student',
        }   

ui = UserInfo(dict_info)

# display original class info
print(dict_info)

# Display changed class info
myinfo = ui.getInfo()
# change "myinfo"
myinfo.update({
   'name ' : 'May',
   'age ' : 18,
   'gender  ' : 'Female',
    'job' : 'lecturer',
})

ui.getInfo()
```

I also wouldn't print a value if your returning it in the method (like what you did in `print(ui.getInfo)`. You could also just creating a new dictionary (making a copy).

Answer (score 0):

Your variable `myinfo` is assigned to `self.info` of the instance of `ui`. So when you modify `myinfo` you are also modifying `self.info` of ui.

I'm not really sure what you are trying to do with myinfo. If you want two different `UserInfo` you need to create another instance like this

```
ui = UserInfo()

ui2 = UserInfo()

myinfo = ui2.getInfo()

myinfo.update({
    'name ' : 'May',
    'age ' : 18,
    'gender  ' : 'Female',
    'job' : 'lecturer',
})

print(ui.getInfo())
print(myinfo)
```

Output

```
{'name ': 'John', 'age ': 20, 'gender  ': 'Male', 'job': 'student'}
{'name ': 'May', 'age ': 18, 'gender  ': 'Female', 'job': 'lecturer'}
```

If you only want to have a different info then you need to use a copy of what is returned.

Answer (score 0):

One way to prevent this from happening would be to have getInfo return a copy of info rather than info itself, and another way (as Green05's answer states), would be to copy the result of getInfo.

First solution:

```py
class UserInfo():
    def __init__(self):
        self.level = 1
        self.type = 'A'
        self.info = {
            'name ' : 'John',
            'age ' : 20,
            'gender  ' : 'Male',
            'job' : 'student',
        }

    def getInfo(self):
        return self.info.copy()
```

Second solution:
`myInfo = ui.getInfo().copy()`

The reason this happens is because Python allows changing attributes in a class externally, regardless of if they're aliased to something else. ui.info is aliased to myInfo, so changing myInfo is really just changing ui.info.

Comment: Thanks for replied. It work fine with return ```.copy()``` when i do ```myinfo.update```, but when the dict contain another dict, its not working again (I already edit my post)

Answer (score 0):

What's happening is that when you return `self.info`, you aren't returning the *value* of the dictionary in `self.info`, you are actually returning the dictionary object itself that the name `self.info` points to. The reason changing the new variable also changes the information in the class object is because that variable is just another name for `self.info` now. You can fix this by returning a copy of the dictionary, which will create a new dictionary object seperate from the original. This can be done with the `copy()` method, which returns a new copy of the dictionary, like this:

```py
class UserInfo():
    def __init__(self):
        self.level = 1
        self.type = 'A'
        self.info = {
            'name ' : 'John',
            'age ' : 20,
            'gender  ' : 'Male',
            'job' : 'student',
        }

    def getInfo(self):
        return self.info.copy()
```

Comment: Thanks for replied. It work fine with return ```.copy()``` when i do ```myinfo.update```, but when the dict contain another dict, its not working again (I already edit my post)

Answer (score -1):

Python dictionaries are mutable. Mutable objects are passed by reference in Python so when you update a reference the changes are reflected in the original. You can get around this by creating a copy of the object.

```py
import copy

ui = UserInfo()
myinfo = copy.copy(ui.getInfo())

myinfo.update({
    'name ' : 'May',
    'age ' : 18,
    'gender  ' : 'Female',
    'job' : 'lecturer',
})

print(myinfo)
# {
#   'name ' : 'May',
#   'age ' : 18,
#   'gender  ' : 'Female',
#   'job' : 'lecturer',
# }

print(ui.getInfo())
# {
#    'name ' : 'John',
#    'age ' : 20,
#    'gender  ' : 'Male',
#    'job' : 'student',
# }
```

Comment: "Mutable objects are passed by reference " No, they aren't. Python uses a *single* evaluation strategy, regardless of type, which is call by object sharing, sometimes referred to as "call by assignment". Python **never** uses call by reference (nor call by value)